# Packery Horizontal Layout Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, packery

Hoping that someone out there has some experience with packery, which I'm using for a project.

I cannot get the horizontal layout to work.  Declaring the packery object in HTML seems to work somewhat.

```
<div class="packery js-packery" data-packery-options='{ "isHorizontal": true }'>
...
</div>
```

Although it appears that the width and height are not changed through CSS as the documents suggest.  But I've not bothered digging further because I need to use Javascript.  And the equivalent doesn't seem to work at all:

```
$('.packery').packery({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isHorizontal: true,
});
```

This results in the `<div>` element the packery object was assigned to 0px high and 4px wide.  (The 4px width probably comes from some items' 1px border.)  The [packery docs](http://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html#ishorizontal) say that horizontal layout requires setting height.  But the CSS provided by the docs seems to do nothing, whether packery was initialized in HTML or Javascript:

```
/* containers need height set when horizontal */
.packery.horizontal {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Still, none of my inserted items are visible and the packery `<div>` is 4px x 0px.  So, I forced the container's height in Javascript:

```
$('.packery').css('height', '400px');
```

This does increase the element's height but the width remains at four.  And therefore all the elements are essentially zero width and invisible.  So, I tried forcing the container's width:

```
$('.packery').css('width', '1000px');
```

But this width seems to be ignored.  I can force the `<div>`'s width using the element editor in Chrome's developer mode, and that produces some visible, although ugly, content.  But how the hang do I set the `<div>`'s width in Javascript?  It seems packery is overriding the width I set, whether I do it before or after the call to `packery()`.

Everything in packery seems to work great for vertical layouts.  But I really want to use the horizontal layout but I'm obviously doing something wrong.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with the isHorizontal option. I solved it using `!important` tag in my css on the `div` width around the packery.